# Ubuntu 22.04 nvidia gpu immediately puts display port connected monitors in standby mode

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 22.04, displayport

**Setup and Problem**

I'm running a Ubuntu 22.04 with a Nvidia RTX 3070-ti with two monitors. The GPU has 1 hdmi port and 3 display ports. Whichever monitor is plugged into the hdmi slot is by the  detected and propagates a signal correctly and well. Whichever monitor I plug into the display ports seems to receive a signal but is immediately put into standby mode. None of the debugging tools I've checked recognize the display port connection is even there but the monitor seems to know it's plugged in. I would like some help diagnosing and fixing my computer so that I can use both my monitors.

Another note: I'm running the ubuntu unity desktop on lightdm and am using the the graphics driver nvidia-driver-525-open. My motherboard is an asus rog strix x570-e so no integrated GPU.

My monitor setup last worked prior to updating from 21.10 to 22.04. However, once I updated to 22.04, I noticed that over time, the second monitor would cease working after suspending the computer or letting the monitors go into screensaver mode. I would have to plug and replug the display port cable into various ports on the gpu until it would give a signal. I did notice that using a separate cable didn't make much of a difference and would continue to have the same fickle behavior. Eventually, this workaround stopped working however. As of writing this post, I noticed that only one of my monitor's display ports respond to a display port cable. The other one makes the monitor think it's not receiving any signal.

**Logs**

Stackexchange thinks my logs make this question look like spam, so I'm moving the logs to a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/mt1GNpeh

**Things I've tried**

I've changed between multiple nvidia drivers and xorg-nouveau, swapped hdmi cables, swapped display port cables, tried gpu passthrough, and swapped between lightdm and gdm. Nothing seems to work.

I've referred to a few other posts on stackexchange and nvidia's website:

- [Ubuntu 22.04 : No display signal from device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412695/ubuntu-22-04-no-display-signal-from-device)
- [Ubuntu 22.04 displayport cutting in and out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417105/ubuntu-22-04-displayport-cutting-in-and-out)
- [DisplayPort monitor not detected if switched off and on again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546818/displayport-monitor-not-detected-if-switched-off-and-on-again)
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/external-monitor-issue-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-using-nvidia-510-and-470-proprietary-drivers/214152
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/hdmi-and-dp-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-22-04/213439/8
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-no-signal-after-monitor-sleep-or-monitor-turned-off/180056/2?page=2
- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/nvidia-rtx-460-display-port-monitor-ubuntu-20-04/22624

**Things I haven't tried**

Trying a brand new display port cable, swapping out a monitor, or purge all the nvidia drivers and do a complete fresh install of nvidia.

Any help or pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The "-open" NVIDIA driver is in alpha quality. Try the other ones.

Comment: I've tried all the available drivers I have: nvidia-driver-525-open, nvidia-driver-470-server, nvidia-driver-510, nvidia-driver-515-server, nivida-driver-515, nvidia-driver-525, nvidia-driver-515-open, nvidia-driver-470, and xserver-xorg-video-nouveau.
None of these fix get my second monitor to work and most of them except nivida-driver-515 have some weird side effect on my computer.

Comment: After working with some folx on the nvidia forum: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gpu-display-ports-are-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-an-rtx-3070-ti/238384/3, I'm going to conclude my gpu is defective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment to my own post.

> After working with some folx on the nvidia forum:
> https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gpu-display-ports-are-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-an-rtx-3070-ti/238384/3, I'm going to conclude my gpu is
> defective.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorted with the following, sorry if this doesn't sort it for you:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Followed by

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

as per [this article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04)

[deleted my blurb about suffering from the same issues]

Comment: This is an issue where the driver is just defective. I have to get it replaced.